# Unable to validate "non-value" input field with ParsleyJS

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I have an input field which uses the `value` property as a mask, so I need to find a way to validate the field that uses an unmasked value.

I tried using the `data-parsley-value` property, but I believe I am using it incorrectly.

From the docs for `data-parsley-value`:

> Set a specific field value for Parsley validation, dissociated from
>   the real one. eg: data-parsley-value="foo"

I've tried both ways for this and both do not seem to work:

```
<input id="myInput" value="$123" min="0" type="tel" data-parsley-value="test" test="-123">
<input id="myInput" value="$123" min="0" type="tel" data-parsley-value="-123">
```

I would normally expect `$('#myInput').parsley().validate()` to throw some sort of error, but it doesn't.

I cannot find any example usage for this property except in that part of the docs, which doesn't help me much. Would someone be able to provide proper usage?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Your given examples don't have a `value` attribute. Could you provide an example with a `value` and say if it should validate or not?

Comment: Hi, I updated my example to show a value. These values are what I'd like to display to the user. However, the value I would like to evaluate is in another attribute.

Comment: I am just having trouble understanding the docs for this property. Would you be able to provide a better example of its usage?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out - "data-parsley-value" is the value it validates instead of the .val() value.

So in your case you'd set:

$({field name}).attr('data-parsley-value', '-123')

or

and then it would validate against that attribute value.